# I can't seem to pass a value to javascript function

Tags: javascript

My code is like so

```js
function show_file(itemid) {
  document.getElementById("itemid").innerHTML = "Testing";
}
```

```html
<td id='$itemid' class='header-row'>
  MyText quote&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <button onclick='show_file($itemid)'>
    Button<i class='fa fa-angle-down'></i>
  </button>
</td>
```

But I get this error "Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null" so it seems the value of $itemid is not getting passed?

Comment: `document.getElementById("itemid")` -> `document.getElementById(itemid)`

Comment: What's `$itemid`? I'm not familiar with this syntax. Ah, you probably meant `"$itemid"`, although it's rather unusual to give a sigil to an id name.

Comment: Also `onclick='show_file($itemid)'` most likely needs to be `onclick='show_file("$itemid")'`

Comment: @ggorlen I assume it's some placeholder that gets changed later via some sort of templating. But it's just a guess.

Comment: It's actually the value of the id of the td element.

Comment: FYI, the $itemid is a php variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you gived a string in parameter to your getElementById function and not the itemid variable. Try this :

```
function show_file(itemid) {
  document.getElementById(itemid).innerHTML = "Testing";
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! :) I thought it would be the solution but no, I don't see what it could be then...

Comment: Thank you, it was the quotes in the javascript that was the problem!

Answer (score 1):

You should pass the actual function's parameter `itemid` not the string "itemid"

Change it from:

```
function show_file(itemid) {
  document.getElementById("itemid").innerHTML = "Testing";
}
```

To:

```
function show_file(itemid) {
  document.getElementById(itemid).innerHTML = "Testing";
}
```

Comment: What the value $itemid have to hold? Should it point to the parent div `<td id='$itemid'...`?

Comment: I assume it was meant to be a string, or at least that's the easiest way to get it to work.